# CSS: Margin-bottom not showing

Tags: html, css

I just know I'm probably being a bit silly here, and overlooking something really obvious... But why doesn't my margin-bottom (12px) appear between the two `div`-elements with id's `row1` and `row2`, respectively? They both belong to class `articles_row`, for which I have set `margin-bottom: 12px;`. So the `margin-bottom` of element `row1` should be clearly visible between `row1` and `row2`... right? No external style sheets used, just what is shown below. This is it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <style>
            .articles_row {
                margin-bottom: 12px;
                color: green;
            }
            .article_left {
                float: left;
                width: 48%;
                border: solid 2px #D74447;
            }
            .article_right {
                float: right;
                width: 48%;
                border: solid 2px #D74447;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="articles_row" id="row1">
            <div class="article_left">  <p>This is left. </p> </div>
            <div class="article_right"> <p>This is right.</p> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="articles_row" id="row2">        
            <div class="article_left">  <p>This is left. </p> </div>
            <div class="article_right"> <p>This is right.</p> </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: everything here seems ok [take one look](https://jsfiddle.net/ykwurd71/) which browser are you using?

Comment: not sure what you're after - something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/4ngbohzq/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
    .articles_row {
        margin-bottom: 12px;
        color: green;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

It works because the floats on the child divs are causing them to "jump out" of the parent div. Open the page in your browser and use the inspection tool to see what is going on. The .articles_row divs actually did have bottom margins, but the divs themselves were both 0 height and were both at the top of the page, overlapping each other, while the child divs were displaying as they would if the parent divs were not there at all.

Floats can be confusing in CSS, but you'll get there! :)

Comment: Remember to accept the answer so others can easily see that it worked

Comment: But how do I accept the answer?
And to ask one more thing: I take it the necessity of adding "overflow: hidden" has something to do with the use of floating elements?

Comment: Yes it does. It's quite a large topic though, far too much to explain here. Worth researching though if you're going to do much work with CSS. Also get used to using the inspection tool, right click on your browser window and choose 'Inspect Element' and be amazed!

Comment: Ah, I just saw how to accept the answer, and have done so.

Comment: Thanks again, Darren.